# Where should i put my C# if statement, for the case my sql query comes back blank?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-ce

Where can i put an if-statement saying that: if the sql query comes back empty, then `Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, empty...whatnot");`

I don't know how to check to see if the result of the query is empty.

This is my code:

```
public void IsMovieInStore()
{
    Console.Write("Searh for a movie title: ");
    string title = Console.ReadLine();

    string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VideoStoreDB.sdf";
    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Movie.Title, MovieHandler.InStore FROM Movie INNER JOIN MovieHandler ON Movie.MovieCodeLable = MovieHandler.MovieCodeLable WHERE MovieHandler.InStore = 1 AND Movie.Title = @title", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);

    SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Movie");


    foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName + ": " + row[column]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: All the `SqlCe*` objects are `IDisposable` and should be used within a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check this by assigning `dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Movie");` to an `int` variable. The Fill method returns the number of rows that are added to or refreshed in the dataset. See msdn for more information: [**DataAdapter.Fill Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
int rows = dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Movie");

if(rows > 0)
{
    //process data
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no data...");
}
```

Comment: You can fill an existing table/dataset which contains already rows.

Comment: Then it should be emptied first. Because using the other answers (`Tables.Count == 0` ...) will give the same problem as well then. :)

Comment: @Abbas: No, why do you insist on clearing a `DataTable`? It's a valid requirement to load other rows into an existing and filled table. But the second `Fill` could return 0 rows even if the table contains rows. As opposed to this `DataTable.Rows.Count==0` is a fail-safe check.

Comment: @Abbas: However, you're right.  OP wants to know if the query returned something not if the table has data.

Comment: You're right in your first of two comments about the fail-safe check and adding other rows. But this could also be done by check if the number has grown. First time fill: set int, next time fill, check if int has increased. :)

Answer (score 3):

try checking table and row counts

```cs
//....
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Movie");

if (0 == dataSet.Tables.Count || 0 == dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm so lonely");
}

foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
//...
```

Comment: +1 but I prefer comparand at right hand side of the operator. I mean `dataSet.Tables.Count == 0`

Comment: I like Yoda and C, so it was inevitable.

Comment: This is the only fail-safe way. +1

Comment: So in `C` language we use this way, I;ve not seen before?

Comment: an excellent article on the subject can be found at http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use dataset, use datatable:

```
public void IsMovieInStore()
                {
                    Console.Write("Searh for a movie title: ");
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();

                    string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VideoStoreDB.sdf";
                    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

                    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Movie.Title, MovieHandler.InStore FROM Movie INNER JOIN MovieHandler ON Movie.MovieCodeLable = MovieHandler.MovieCodeLable WHERE MovieHandler.InStore = 1 AND Movie.Title = @title", connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);

                    SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);

                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        If(dataTable != null && dataTable.Rows.Count>0)
        {
                     foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName + ": " + row[column]);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                        }
                  }
    }
        else{
          Console.WriteLine("Empty result");
        }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
```